# Visual Studio 2019 Debugging does not work when VPN is connected

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, visual-studio

- OS: Windows 10 (with current latest updates)
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 v.16.4.4

Visual Studio cannot debug an ASP.NET Core 3 web application when the computer is connect to VPN (via Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client). The web application is dockerized and is started via docker-compose.

As mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209932/debugging-not-work-if-we-use-vpn.html) the issue must have been resolved by now; however, at least on my end, it is not resolved yet.

I have tried setting up *remote debugging* following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Attach_to_a_process_on_a_remote_computer), [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34915343/947889), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400637/947889) documentation/suggestions. However, neither help debugging my web application when the computer is connected to VPN.

*I need to keep the computer connected to VPN because the application requires data that are available via my institute's VPN.*

**Copied from [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60141342/947889).**

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without the information that was being requested in the comments to your [cross site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141342/visual-studio-2019-debugging-does-not-work-when-vpn-is-connected).

Comment: Could you please point what specific points are needed?

Comment: "You can use tracert (in a shell) to get that. And I mean the routing table of the OS. You can show or manipulate that with route (also in a shell)."